# Eclipse build overrites jdk version preferences

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have Eclipse OpenJDK11+Gradle2.1.1 project.

I selected 11(BETA) as Java Compiler version on the project property.
That is .settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs is

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=11
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=11
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=11
```

But I edited build.gradle and saved it then the property changed to 1.8.
.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```

And this Eclipse warning message appeared

```
The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 11 is used
```

I tried to add this to build.gradle. But it didn't work.

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
eclipse.jdt.file.withProperties { props ->
    props.setProperty('org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform', '11')
    props.setProperty('org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source', '11')
    props.setProperty('org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance', '11')
}
```

How can I fix JDK version eternally?

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle`, add

```
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
```

Comment: Thnx, emilles.
But these sentenses in my build.gradle already.